# Saving txt file using saveFileDialog (C++)

Tags: c++, iostream, savefiledialog

I can't manage to save a text file using the "saveFileDialog".
I have looked trough many forums and tutorials, but i cant get the right information from neither.
So far i have managed to open the Save file dialog and it actualy saves an empty text file with the right name and path,BUT, and this is the part i have trouble with, its EMPTY, and i dont know where you show what information to save on the file and what methods to use!

Here is the code :

```
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog();
     }
private: System::Void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::CancelEventArgs^  e) {
         System::IO::FileStream ^ fs = safe_cast<System::IO::FileStream^>(saveFileDialog1->OpenFile());
         }
```

So can somebody tell me how and what to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You use the save file dialog to get a path where to save your file. So basically you would need

```
saveFileDialog.showDialog();
String filename = saveFileDialog.FileName;
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename)

file.writeLine("This is a test");
file.close();
```

This is just a quick example :D